# Rest API validation error with @RequestBody and @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, validation

I have implemented rest service and want to do validation on it. In my class I have @RequestBody and @RequestParam. I want to validate both objects. I do that like this:

```
@Controller
@Validated
public class RestApiImpl {

    @Autowired
    ClassA classA;

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/classA",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
            consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ClassAResponse getList(@Valid @RequestBody ClassARequest request,
                                               @Min(value = 1, message = "At least 1 object is expected")
                                               @RequestParam(value = "quantity",defaultValue = "3",required = false) String quantity) {
        return (ClassAResponse) classA.executeService(request);
    }
}

public class ClassARequest {

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 6, message = "tes1")
    private String value1;

    public String getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }

    public void setValue1(String value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
    }
}
```

And the post return 500 internal server error and log:

```
09:49:21,240 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:49:21,240 ERROR [[dispatcher]] Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
javax.validation.ConstraintDeclarationException: Only the root method of an overridden method in an inheritance hierarchy may be annotated with parameter constraints, but there are parameter constraints defined at all of the following overridden methods:
```

When I remove @Validated @RequestBody is validated and works fine but validation for @RequestParam is not working. And If I remove @Valid from @RequestBody validation for request is not working. How to configure this that it work for both @RequestBody and @RequestParam. Or there isn't any solution and only way is to move param quantity to request?

spring framework 3.2.18.RELEASE and hibernate-validator 4.2.0.Final (it can't be changed to newer version for spring and hibernate)